# What does "Candygram" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

[image]

Candygram? What does it mean? I read this entry, but it didn't make sense.

> [Candygram](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/candygram)
>   candy that can be ordered by wire for delivery with an accompanying message, as on the recipient's birthday or anniversary.

The caption on the image says:

> A: Assault happened sometime after they closed, a little after 2:00. Bodyguard Luis Lopez was hit first. Frankie Adkins, he's the owner of the bar, he was hit next. We ID'd the body as Isaac Proctor.
>
> B: Proctor? Name's familiar.
>
> A: Isaac is the son of cirminal defense attorney Amanda Proctor.
>
> B: I dealt with her. She's kept a lot of bad people on the street.
>
> C: So someone kills her son. Is someone trying to send a message?
>
> A: If they are, it's a pretty brutal **candygram**.
>
> B: Sword. It's pretty old-school.
>
> C: Any witnesses?

...

Comment: It would probably make more sense if we knew what they were looking at. Is candy somehow involved in the crime scene? More context would be useful. (Although I'll assume that there's candy on the ground; in which case, the given answer is appropriate.)

Comment: @JasonBassford No, there is nothing about candy in that scene.

Comment: In that case, it's being used in a very figurative way, and there is a lot of "dark humour" around the fact that the dead body *itself* is being referred to as "candy."

Comment: What's the show?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

***Candygram*** a derived form of the word *telegram*, where the suffix -*gram* means "sent from someone else".

Officially, NOAD says that the suffix *-gram* means:

> in nouns, denoting something written or recorded (especially in a certain way):
>     *cryptogram* | *heliogram*.

However, at least informally, the suffix -*gram* has come to be used by companies that deliver things other than messages, presumably because *candygram* sounded more catchy than *telecandy*. Other quaint forms I've heard include [*pajamagram*](https://www.pajamagram.com/), a website that lets you order pajamas online and send them to someone else as a gift. There are websites called *flowergram* and *candygram* as well, and [kissograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singing_telegram#Kissogram) have been around for some time.

If I sent you a candygram, it might look something like this:

[image]

That explains what a *candygram* is. In the crime drama you are citing, a pun is being made on the phrase "send a message.” In the criminal underworld, when we *send a message to someone*, that means we are warning them about something we don't appreciate, often under a threat or act of violence. (As an example, there's the famous [horse head scene in the movie *The Godfather*](https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/horse-head-in-godfather-real-event.htm).)

So when they see the victim on the street, one investigator asks, "Are they trying to send a message?" meaning, "Are they trying to intimidate someone, or maybe warn some group about more potential violence?"

The other makes a grim joke, because one way to send a message (like a nice message, to a close friend) is a Candygram. He may have just as well said, “If so, it’s a pretty brutal message indeed,” but I assume the writers thought the use of the word “Candygram” would make the dialogue seem more clever. This sort of verbal exchange is not uncommon on television crime shows.

Comment: "where the suffix -gram means "sent from someone else". " - side note: etymologically it's the *tele* part of *telegram* which indicates remoteness, while *gram* refers to it being written down (after all, an "angiogram" does not involve sending arteries via mail). So while words like "candygram" and "kissogram" have been accepted in English in favor of "telecandy" or "telekiss",  it's not a general rule that "gram" means "sent from somewhere/someone else".

Comment: @MaciejStachowski. Historically, you are right. But J.R.'s point is that now, in current English, the _-gram_ suffix **does** mean exactly  that.

Comment: The joke here may relate to the use of "Candygram" in the movie "Blazing Saddles", where an exploding candy-gram is delivered to one of the movie's principal villains.

Comment: @J.R. You know dear J.R. as far as I'm aware the word **pun** means : an amusing use of a word or phrase that **has TWO meanings**, but actually I don't think that the words "CANDY" or "CANDYGRAM" are commonly used with these two meanings in everyday English: 1. a sweet food made from sugar or chocolate a ___gram of these foods 2. a nice message, to a close friend

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi - You misunderstand where the pun is; the pun is not in the word “candygram”, but in the phrase “send a message”. In the criminal underworld, _send a message_ means deliver a stern warning. That’s meaning #1; it only becomes a pun when the other character says the message is a “brutal candygram”, which is another kind of message altogether. But my original answer didn't delve into all that, because your original question was [insufficiently detailed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/0700ef61-4c0b-45db-a3c3-157c1302d022/view-source). Answer amended.